# How to use an imported function in a loop with the loop variable inside that function?

Tags: python, bash

In bash I have a file "`function.sh`":

```
_bash_function_() { 
echo $i
   }
```

and a file "`exec.sh`"

```
#!/bin/bash

. ./function.sh

range=(1 2 3)

for i in ${range[@]}; do
    _bash_function_
done
```

That gives the output:

```
1
2
3
```

In python I have a file "`function.py`":

```
def py_function():
    print (i)
```

And a file "`exec.py`":

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3

from function import *

list = ['1','2','3']

for i in list:
    py_function()
```

This gives an error:

```
NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

However if I have the function and the loop in the same file:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/python3

def py_function():
    print (i)

list = ['1','2','3']

for i in list:
    py_function()
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
```

How can I have this output in Python, with the function in one file, and the loop in the other ?

Comment: There are a few key differences between `bash` and Python here. First, `bash` variables are truly globals, since you don't really have modules; `source` simply executes code *exactly* as if it appeared in the current file. In `py_function`, `i` refers to `function.i`, not the distinct variable `exec.i` (or `__main__.i`, depending on how the file gets executed). Second (and not immediately relevant here), `bash` uses dynamic scoping, which means a nonlocal variable references the scope where the function is *called*, not where it is *defined*. Python uses static scoping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the main points of functions is that they accept arguments. In your case, you should define the function so that it accepts `i` as an argument:

```
def py_function(i):
    print (i)
```

and pass it when you call it:

```
for i in list:
    py_function(i)
```